# Check for a string using .contains()

Tags: json

Below is the code which works perfectly for normal strings. But when I pass Json.serialize result as string, below method is not working.

```
list<case> c = [select id, casenumber from case limit 5];
String myString1 = JSON.serialize(c);
system.debug(myString1);

String myString2 = 'case';
Boolean result = myString1.contains(myString2);
system.debug(result);
```

Comment: It would help if you added the output of the debug statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contains()` is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe... use `.containsIgnoreCase()` and you should get the expected result.